# Export 3D colored model of scanned environment with LiDAR scanner in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, lidar

I am working on POC that export scanned area using LiDAR scanner into a colored 3D format.

I am following the apple example.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/world_tracking/visualizing_and_interacting_with_a_reconstructed_scene

But it gives results in a grayed scale.

I want this to be exported 3D model in actual color.

Can anyone have an idea about this?

I see that many apps are doing the same.

Comment: Have you got any solution to achieve this?